# What happens to user input in gitlab-ci script

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

I am wondering what happens if a command in a gitlab-ci.yml configuration asks for user input?

```
test1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bash script.sh
```

and script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will test if you have given a leap year or not.

echo "Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:"

read year
```

I think this is a pretty standard situation, but I never thought about it before.

The same might be the problem if one executes the same script non-interactively in docker:

```
docker exec container_name bash script.sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's a build step that asks user input, the build simply fails. You cannot ask for user input in GitLab CI builds.

Comment: To confirm: I have tested this with your code:  `Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1`

Comment: Thanks! I found out that some packages have default values that are used in this case, this has lead to some hidden problems in my case. Thanks again!